# Apply map operator in RxJS to only part of the Object

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a response object in the following format:

```
{
'akey':'avalue',
'bkey':'bvalue',
'ckey':'cvalue',
'arrKey':[{'a':'A','t':1},{'b':'B','t':2},{'c':'C','t':3}]
}
```

I want to apply the map operator in RxJS to only the elements of 'arrKey'.Something like the below,

```
this.http.get(url)
.map(res=>res.json())
.map(res['arrKey']=>res['arrKey']['t']=res['arrKey']['t']*2)
```

which after subscribed to results in

```
{
'akey':'avalue',
'bkey':'bvalue',
'ckey':'cvalue',
'arrKey':[{'a':'A','t':2},{'b':'B','t':4},{'c':'C','t':6}]
}
```

Is there a function to apply map to a specific part of object and leave the rest unchanged?

Comment: Nope, youll need to pass the individual objects by a map, mutate the object and return it, all inside of the map operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be as simple as `.map(res => res.json()).pluck('arrKey').map(transformFn)`, but I think what you are asking is that you want to do a transformation on `arrKey` and also pass all of the other properties. You can just do this as a synchronous logical operation inside of a `.map`:

```
.map(res => res.json())
.map(response => {
  response.arrKey = response.arrKey.map(arrKey => ({ ...arrKey, t: arrKey.t * 2 }));
  return response;
});
```

Comment: this just adds a new key-value pair 't' with the value of NaN to the response. It does not apply map on each element of arrKey.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your question. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 2):

If you expect the full response to be emitted from the map method, then you need to return the entire response, but modify it within the map method.

```
.map(res => {
    res['arrKey'].forEach(item => {
        item['t'] = item['t'] * 2;
    });
    return res;
});
```

Comment: this does work, but its not a very 'reactive' way to go. I could do this after subscribe too. I was wondering whether there's an operator that just transforms(applies map to) a part of the object, and leaves others unchanged